# why does pip not comply with minimal dependencies?

Tags: python, pip

For my Python package, I have a setup.py file where I specify requirements:

```
install_requires=['numpy>=1.7', 'matplotlib>=1.3'],
```

When I use pip install, it nicely recognizes that I have specified these requirements, and then proceeds to update numpy while my numpy version was higher than the required one.

```
Collecting numpy>=1.7 (from flopy)
Downloading numpy-1.11.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (3.9MB)
Fund existing installation: numpy 1.10.1
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling numpy-1.10.1:
Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.10.1
```

I have talked to several people and they all report the same behavior. Why is this? How do I specify the numpy requirement correctly?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly?" You are simply asking for pip a `numpy` version greater than 1.7, which it is happily complying with.

Comment: Well, the specification says `numpy>=1.7`, the installed version is 1.10.1, so it should not upgrade to 1.11.0, because 1.10.1 >= 1.7. Is that not the intended behavior?

Answer (score 2):

pip is installing a version of `numpy` that is greater than 1.7. Which is what you specified. If you're looking for an exact match of the version you want, you can try something like:

```
install_requires=['numpy==1.7', ... ]
```

Or if you want to specify a particular range you can do:

```
install_requires['numpy>=1.7,<1.10' ... ]
```

Comment: But my machine already had numpy 1.10.1, which is greater than 1.7. I thought the behavior was that if the version is larger than the requirement, then pip will not upgrade. Isn't that what it is supposed to do? To be more precise: I want setup to check whether the version is at least 1.7 and if that is the case, then do nothing, if that is not the case, upgrade numpy. Is that possible?

Comment: I believe that is the behavior yes. My guess with your problem then, is that the pip that you were installing from (I don't know if you were using sudo or from a different virtual environment) didn't know that numpy 1.10.1 was installed.